# How Do I "Extend" a view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on an open source project and due to different versions, there's the issue where I can't count on there being a controller for a view. Instead this email would be send out via a rake task for one version and a few others would done via a controller. Now you understand why I'm asking a bad practice question...

I have a layout for a view. Does anyone know a way to specify what the layout is for the view within the view. Some pseudo-code:

```
<%= extends 'layout/test_mailer` %>
<h1> Hey there! </h1>
```

And the layout would have the usual `yield` within it.

I hope I'm explaining the problem good enough.

Comment: wow... awful, but I can see why you need it. Really interesting question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using **yield** and **content_for** should solve the problem. [[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield)]

```
# my_layout.html.erb

<%= yield :mail_view %>

# my_mail_view.html.erb

<%= content_for :mail_view do %>
  <!-- html -->
<% end %>
```

Of-course, if you are using params to get the layout, this would be a wrong answer.

Then, you can also use:

```
<%= render partial: "link_area", layout: "graybar" %>
```

Answer (score 5):

`<%= render partial: "hey_page", layout: "layout/test_mailer" %>`

Check part **3.4.3 Partial Layouts** at [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: I don't know if this works yet, but +1 for referencing the Guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//controller action
def index 
    render layout: test_mailer
end

//view, index.html.erb
<h1> Hey there! </h1>

//view, layout/test_mail.html.erb
<html>....layout for you test mail  
<% yield %>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I can't assume that I'll have a controller for the mailer.